How can I draw and adjust the max and min values of the curves?
I am trying to reproduce this chart with tikz and its corresponding packages but I can't do the follwing:

properly allocate the curves with their respective shapes and maximum and minimum values
Align the points 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 to show the respective economic concepts


I include the code I was able to build so far:
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

% Required packages
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% Set pgfplots version and style
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,angles,quotes,intersections}

% Document begins
\begin{document}

 % Title
\begin{center}
\Large{Monopolistic Competition - Long-run Equilibrium}
\end{center}

% Create the plot
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2]
% Style definitions
\tikzset{
    every node/.style={font=\footnotesize},
    axis/.style={thick, ->},
    curve/.style={thick, smooth},
}

% Define coordinates for curves
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\coordinate (X) at (8,0);
\coordinate (Y) at (0,8);

% Draw axes
\draw[axis] (O) -- (X) node[right] {$Q$};
\draw[axis] (O) -- (Y) node[above] {$P$};

% Draw ATC curve (orange)
\draw[orange, curve] plot[domain=0.2:7, smooth, tension=0.5] 
    coordinates {(0.2,7) (2,5.2) (4,5.2) (6,6)};

% Draw MC curve (green) - convex with minimum at x=1
\draw[green!50!black, curve] plot[domain=0.2:7, smooth, tension=0.5] 
    coordinates {(0.2,6) (1,4.5) (2,4.7) (4,5.2) (6,6.5)};

% Draw Demand curve (blue)
\draw[blue, curve] plot[domain=0:7, smooth, tension=0.5] 
    coordinates {(0,7.5) (2,6.5) (4,5.6) (6,4.7) (7,4.2)};

% Draw MR curve (blue)
\draw[blue, curve] plot[domain=0:7, smooth, tension=0.5] 
    coordinates {(0,7.5) (2,6) (4,4.6) (6,3.2) (7,2.5)};

% Add labels for curves with backgrounds
\node[right, fill=white, inner sep=1pt] at (7,7.2) {D=AR=P};
\node[right, fill=white, inner sep=1pt] at (7,4) {MR};
\node[left, fill=white, inner sep=1pt] at (1,4.8) {MC};
\node[left, fill=white, inner sep=1pt] at (1,5.5) {ATC};

% Add equilibrium point
\fill[green!80] (4,5.6) circle (2pt);

% Add dashed lines for equilibrium
\draw[red, dashed] (4,0) -- (4,5.6);
\draw[red, dashed] (0,5.6) -- (4,5.6);

% Add numbered points at equilibrium
\node[circle, draw, fill=white, inner sep=1pt] at (4,5.6) {1};
\node[circle, draw, fill=white, inner sep=1pt] at (4.2,5.6) {2};
\node[circle, draw, fill=white, inner sep=1pt] at (4.4,5.6) {3};

% Add gridlines (optional - comment out if not needed)
%\draw[gray!30, thin] (0,1) grid (7,7);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

Which results the following:


Some hints. // For your code the only package you need is: Tikz ... all other are not needed to compile your code and would trigger useless updates for users. // Name the curves, i.e. their paths. Look for intersect and use the solutions. // Most curves can be done by a simple draw, using to[] instead of --.

You can use the intersections tikzlibrary to locate the intersections (use name path=...).  For MC and ATC, pick better points.  In fact three points per curve and a possibly a higher tension will do.

While you are waiting for tikz-help, here is a version Metapost, for comparison, and hopefully inspiration!

Compile this source with lualatex to get a PDF that looks like this ^^^
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{arev}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
  % parameters to control the placement of the curves + lines
  numeric s, t; s = 2.236; t = 1.45;  
  
  % define the curves, lines and axes
  % and define the intersection points z1..z5 as we go along
  path unit_parabola, atc, mc, darp, mr, xx, yy;
  unit_parabola = (-1,1){1,-2}..(-1/2,1/4){1,-1}..(0,0){1,0}..(1/2,1/4){1,1}..(1,1){1,2};

  mc = subpath (5/4,4) of unit_parabola xscaled 144 yscaled 233 shifted (80,50);

  z1 = point s of mc;
  atc = unit_parabola scaled 144 shifted z1;

  % size the axes to the atc curve
  xx = origin -- (xpart point 4 of atc, 0);
  yy = origin -- (0, ypart point 0 of atc);
  
  z2 = point t of atc;
  darp = (left -- right) scaled 200
    rotated angle direction t of atc
    shifted z2 cutbefore yy;

  z3 = mc intersectionpoint (z2--(x2,0));
  z4 = mc intersectionpoint darp;

  numeric a; a = angle (z2 - point 0 of darp) - angle(z3 - point 0 of darp);
  mr = darp rotatedabout(point 0 of darp, -a);
  z5 = darp intersectionpoint yy shifted (mr intersectionpoint xx);

  % now draw the curves and lines with a thick pen
  drawoptions(withpen pencircle scaled 1);
    drawarrow xx;
    drawarrow yy;
    draw darp withcolor 3/4 blue;
    draw mr   withcolor 3/4 blue;
    draw mc   withcolor 2/3 green;
    draw atc  withcolor (red + 3/4 green);
  drawoptions();

  % add the Pf Qf leaders
  drawoptions(dashed evenly scaled 1/2 withcolor 1/2 red);
    draw (0,y2) -- z2 -- (x2,0); 
    draw           z5 -- (x5,0);
  drawoptions();

  % label the 5 points
  picture c;
  c = image(
    fill fullcircle scaled 9 withcolor 3/4[green, white]; 
    draw fullcircle scaled 9;
  );
  for i=1 upto 5:
    draw c shifted z[i];
    label(TEX(decimal i) scaled 0.7, z[i]);
  endfor

  % add the remaining labels
  label.urt("$MC$",    point length mc of mc);
  label.urt("$ATC$",   point length atc of atc);
  label.rt("$D=AR=P$", point 1 of darp);
  label.rt("$MR$",     point 1 of mr);

  label.bot("$Q_f$", (x2,0));
  label.lft("$P_f$", (0,y2));

  label.rt ("$Q$", point 1 of xx);
  label.top("$P$", point 1 of yy);

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}

Follow the link at the top for tutorials and references for MP.
